# Mathematica Wont Open

Tags: notebooks

Mathematica 10 will not open on my computer which runs Windows 8. It is stuck on the initializing kernals screen regardless of whether I try to open the program or open an old document. The problem only started today (9/4/2015) and prior to this was working perfectly. Desperate for a fix because I need to do a lab

Comment: There is little no information in your post, so it's not likely anyone here can help you. In most cases you need to provide details that describe your issue and a minimal working example allowing it to be tested.

Comment: Clear the cache ?

Comment: I've had the same issue today on an iMac "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)", no truble so far on MacBookPro, the cure is indeed [Front end freezes on start-up](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/front-end-freezes-on-start-up)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and followed the instructions in this post:
[Front end freezes on start-up](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/front-end-freezes-on-start-up)

i.e.delete paclets file and disable auto-update. It's dirty, but it fixed the issue in that I can now actually use mathematica.

Comment: AFAIK there is not a proper fix that I have found yet.

Comment: My issue started yesterday btw (9/3/15) so I am not sure if this is a recent update thing or what - especially considering that internet connectivity is related.

Comment: Here's the reason and the solution: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/mathematica-10-0-x-freezes-in-initializing-kernels

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that this solution worked for me.