# Mathematica doens't open on my mac. Used it yesterday night

Tags: installation

Something strange is happening to my program. These are some of the details of my computer:[image]

I used mathematica yesterday and all it does today is bounce on the dock and then stop only to freeze and then I have to force quit.

I suspect maybe it is freezing trying to open previous worksheets or something like that; although it never did before...

Is there some file I should delete in the program's contents? What can I do as I need this program pretty urgently?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931

Comment: Take a look at these questions: ([92931](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92931/27951)), ([90021](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90021/27951)) and see if you are experiencing the same issue. Fixes are proposed.

Comment: I'll check them out, thanks.

Comment: I experience a similar problem under Mac OSX 10.10.5 when coming out of sleep mode. But not only with Mathematica 10.2.0, also other programs start up very slowly, e.g.TextEdit, Pages, Activity Monitor, ..., which are native Mac programs. I did not have this problem with 10.10.4. The only third party program I recently added is iStat (which I find very useful).

Comment: I had the same problem, solution was to use gfxCardStatus to disable the automatic switching of graphic cards and to use "Discrete Only".