# How can I recover from front end crash after debug session?

Tags: front-end, crash, raspberry-pi

On *Mathematica* 10.3 running on Raspberry Pi 3, the debug session on the Front End hung and I had to kill the Front End. 
( I now know better: better  'kill -9' the Kernel process and not the Front End).

Anyhow, now the Front End will not start. The front end attempts to start, displays the Wolfram logo, reports  "initializing the kernel", then momentarily displays the debug window and then shuts down.

Importantly, the wolfram command line session starts okay.

How can I recover from this situation?

the location `/home/pi/.WolframEngine/SystemFiles/FrontEnd` has no large files there or obvious locked items.
I cannot find any logs from which to debug this.

Comment: btw, I have looked at a related question but removing pacletdata has no effect ( I have since replaced those paclet files back into the Configuration directory: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/front-end-freezes-on-start-up

Answer (score 2):

`mathematica -cleanstart` fixed this issue.