# Front-end application freezes on startup

Tags: front-end, crash

I use Mathematica for MAC (11.2.0.0). My front-end application hangs on start-up. There is no splash screen but the Activity Monitor reports the process as non-responsive.

I've found an older thread reporting a similar problem:
[Front end freezes on start-up](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/front-end-freezes-on-start-up)

That solution works for me as well. I have to delete the "pacletSiteData_11.pmd2" file from "~/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration", then the front-end application starts without problems.

I'm just surprised that the problem occurs — the original thread dates back to 2015.

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until other users have confirmed your observations.

Comment: There does not seem to be a question in this post.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer, erase and download again.